# rest api - sending and receiving image

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I have created in my api method

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(int id, [FromForm]IFormFile file)
```

which is saving user image to database as byteArray

```
  user.UserDetails.AvatarImage = stream.ToArray();
```

And i have folllowing questions:

1)When client asks API for user dto should i return byte[] as an avatar and the client should somehow display it?

2) How should i send request from my client, let's say from wpf client.
How should i prepare data in my Http Put action <-- i dont know what should i put in content (im sending it as json, but i don't know how to send picture as IFromFile) I'have tried my api using restlet client extension from google chrome
and i would like to send put request from code which would be similar to this:
[image]

i mean, in WPF application i get an image from user, let's say i have some Stream and how can i send it as IFromFile (i don't want to reference to aspnetcoremvc...)

Comment: A webpage is http that does not allow binary data like images to be transferred.  So you must convert to a 64 bit stream using ConvertTo64Sttring and ConvertFrom64String.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way would be to not do any of those. When anyone uploads an image, store it in a location which is publicly available via a URL. Then allow the client to just refer to the URL of the image. The serving of the image will automatically be handled by your web server and the display and retrieval of your image will automatically be handled by your client/browser. You do not have to be worried about anything.